# If statement with nested subset function

Tags: r, list, if-statement, dataframe, subset

I am trying to do a if statement with a subset function in it.
I have a dataframe dat1, for example like this:

```
     Unit   Cost    Date
     1        40    Sep
     1        50    Dec
     2        55    Sep
     2        30    Oct
```

And based on its row nrow(dat1) I want to subset an other dataframe (dat2)

```
      unit  model   sales
      1      AAA    100
      1      BBB    110
      1      CCC    130
      4      ZZZ    120
      5      YYY    128
```

I wrote a ifstatement like this:

```
     Sales <- ifelse(nrow(dat1)>=30, 
            dat2[which(dat2$unit==1 & dat2$model=="AAA"),], 
            dat2[which(dat2$unit==1),])
```

So if the nrow>30 I want to apply subset on 2 dimensions of dat2, else just on one of them.
However this gives me a list with only the first column, not a dataframe with all the 3 columns of dat2. 
What is the right command to do this?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use `if` and `else`. This is not a use case for `ifelse`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Sales <- dat2[which(dat2$unit==1),] # default
if (nrow(dat1)>=30) {
    Sales <-dat2[which(dat2$unit==1 & dat2$model=="AAA"),]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if followed by else statements for data subsetting

```
if(nrow(dat1)>=30){ 
Sales <-   dat2[dat2$unit==1 & dat2$model=="AAA",]
}else{
Sales <-   dat2[dat2$unit==1,]}
```